# How to build help for android app

Tags: android

I saw in some android applications that when they start first a helper UI comes to help understand how to work with the app! I have attached a custom screenshot to understand what I mean!

[IMAGE http://8pic.ir/images/fz6so53s177rd3t3o9bv.png](http://8pic.ir/images/fz6so53s177rd3t3o9bv.png)

Please help me, How can I create something like this?

Best Regards, Minallah Tofiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best library I've come across is [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview).

Read the guide and set it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyPreferences {

private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "my_preferences";  

public static boolean isFirst(Context context){
    final SharedPreferences reader = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    final boolean first = reader.getBoolean("is_first", true);
    if(first){
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = reader.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("is_first", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return first;
}
```

}

in your onCreate() function,

```
...
//himg is image view in relative layout with rest of layout so that it covers whole screen
ImageView helpimage = (ImageView) findViewbyId(R.id.himg);
MyPreferences obj = new new MyPreferences();

if(obj.isFirst==true) helpimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

else helpimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To show help as in your posted image, you can use image with transparent background and with arrows and texts only.